# Python Read Text File Split By

Tags: python

I have a text file looks the following:

```
164,http://www.site.com/category1
161,http://www.site.com/category2
162,http://www.site.com/category3
163,http://www.site.com/category4
```

I'm trying to get each time new line category id + category url in a for loop.
I had other method before the code looks like:

```
def main():
    config=ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    config.readfp(open("settings.cfg"),"r")
    for site in config.sections():
       # ipdb.set_trace()
        settings=dict(config.items(site))
        for (url,category) in zip(settings['url'].split(","),settings['category'].split(",")):
```

Can anyone help me change the for of settings.cfg to my text file format?

Using some research I found online this the start of how the code should look like:

```
with open('categories.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
```

but need to strip it by "," and appeand url,category each. But I'm afraid to miss first or last lines by this code will this read it all and work? Some help with this will be great!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a csv file. Try:

```
import csv

with open('categories.txt') as fp:
    for category, url in csv.reader(fp):
        print category, url
```

Comment: It seems to work but there is an error after some lines ``Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "readfile.py", line 4, in <module>
    for category, url in csv.reader(fp):
ValueError: too many values to unpack``

Comment: Well, in that case your file is not consistent regarding the comma-separated values. Could you provide a larger example of the file? The other answers show you how to use `.split(",")` that might work for your case. Otherwise, you could replace the `category, url` with `values` which is going to be a list. Then see how many values you get in that list.

Comment: yes It seems like I had one , at some place removed it and it worked really good. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it.

```
file1 = "myFile.txt";
tFile1 = open(file1,'r')

for line in tFile1.readlines():
    lineParse = line.split(',')
    lineNumber = lineParse[0];
    urlParse = lineParse[1].split('/');
    url = urlParse[2];
    category = urlParse[3];

    print str(lineNumber)+" "+"http://"+str(url)+" "+str(category)
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want to keep those in a list of list,

```
urlcatlist=list()
with open('categories.txt','r') as f:

    for line in f:
        urlcatlist.append(line.strip().split(","))
        #or print
        print(line.strip().split(","))
```